# Nested components in app.vue not pulling content through

Tags: javascript, vue.js

main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import Parent from './assets/components/frame/Parent.vue';
import LeftSide from './assets/components/frame/LeftSide.vue';
import RightSide from './assets/components/frame/RightSide.vue';

import HeaderLeft from './assets/components/header/HeaderLeft.vue';
import HeaderRight from './assets/components/header/HeaderRight.vue';

Vue.component('Parent', Parent);
Vue.component('LeftSide', LeftSide);
Vue.component('RightSide', RightSide);
Vue.component('HeaderLeft', HeaderLeft);
Vue.component('HeaderRight', HeaderRight);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Non working app.vue file, no data appears on web page. When examining the page via dev tools, the parent div is there, but it's empty. I'm expecting the LeftSide and RightSide to be nested inside of it.

```
<template>
<div>
  <Parent>
    <LeftSide>
    </LeftSide>
    <RightSide>
    </RightSide>
  </Parent>
</div>
</template>
<script>
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

When modified to the below (exclude 'Parent'), to have no nested components, the data (left side and right side) outputs to the web page fine.

```
<template>
<div>
    <LeftSide>
    </LeftSide>
    <RightSide>
    </RightSide>
</div>
</template>
<script>
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Parent component below

```
<template>
<div class="parent">
</div>
</template>


<script>
</script>


<style>
.parent
{
  display: flex;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What does the Parent component look like?

Comment: Added. Do I need to nest the leftside and rightside inside that parent file? I thought since I included them inside the parent component in the app.vue it would include them inside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving LeftSide and RightSide into the Parent.vue, instead of having the LeftSide and RightSide inside the Parent in the app.vue.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out yourself you should move those components into the `Parent` component.

But there are situations where you want to have a reusable component as decorator (something like a panel) and place elements inside of it. In this case you are looking for [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html). Using slot you can indeed write this:

```
<Parent>
  <LeftSide />
  <RightSide />
</Parent>
```

And in the `Parent` component you would need to define where those components have to be placed using `<slot></slot>`

```
<template>
<div class="parent">
    <slot></slot>
</div>
</template>


<script>
</script>


<style>
.parent
{
  display: flex;
}
</style>
```